# React throws error when using ajax before redirect

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting the following error:

> Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your
>   application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks
>   in the componentWillUnmount method.
>       in ViewMessage (created by Route)

here is the component in question, as you see there is no componentWillUnmount:

```
class ViewMessage extends React.Component{
  state={
    message: {},
    messageId: '',
    redirect: false,
    reply: false
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state){
    if(props.location.state){
      return { messageId: props.location.state.id };
    }else{
      return { redirect: true}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getMessage()
  }

  getMessage = () => {
    this.setState({_loading: true});
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/getMessage',
      params: {
        id: this.state.messageId
      },
      withCredentials: true
    }).then((result) => {
      this.setState({message: result.data[0], _loading: false});
    })
  }

  handleReply = () => {
    if(this.state.reply){
      this.setState({reply: false});
    }else{
      this.setState({reply: true});
    }
  }


  render(){

    if(this.state.redirect){
      return(
        <Redirect to='/messages' />
      )
    }

    return(
      <Container>
        {this.state.loading ? <Loader active /> : <div></div>}
        <div style={{float: 'right'}}>
          {this.state.message.date}
        </div>
          From: {this.state.message.senderName}
        <Divider />
          Subject: {this.state.message.subject}
        <Divider />
          {this.state.message.text}
        <Divider />
        <Button icon='reply' onClick={this.handleReply}/>
        {this.state.reply ? <Composer recipient={this.state.message.senderName}/> : <div></div>}

      </Container>

    )
  }
}

export default ViewMessage;
```

the error occurred when i added the following line, and disappears when i remove it:

```
    if(this.state.redirect){
      return(
        <Redirect to='/messages' />
      )
    }
```

am i doing something wrong in the render method?

Comment: Are you redirecting before the response from your ajax call returns? From the error message, it sounds like you attempted to set state after the component was unmounted, and the only place I see that being possible is in your `.then()` after your ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution, which is a bit hacky, is this:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    if(!this.state.redirect){
      this.getMessage()      
    }
  }
```

which prevents getMessage from being called when a redirect will happen after mounting.

Answer (score 1):

Promises are a guaranteed future, which means the whole promise chain will fire once invoked and there's little you can do to stop it.

On a practical level, this means you need to check to be sure that your `this` context still exists before trying to access setState off it, as the component may have unmounted before this promise chain completes.

```
getMessage = () => {
    this.setState({_loading: true});
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/getMessage',
      params: {
        id: this.state.messageId
      },
      withCredentials: true
    }).then((result) => {
        if (this) { // be sure the instance still exists!
          this.setState({message: result.data[0], _loading: false});
        }
    })
  }
```

Comment: this seems like it would be a very common pattern to prevent errors when users unmount components before ajax's are returned.... but i've never seen it. also, it doesn't actually prevent the error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a ternary statement? I know ternary statements are typically how people return different components conditionally.

```
render(){
  return(
    this.state.redirect ?
      <Redirect to='/messages' />
    :
      <Container>
        {this.state.loading ? <Loader active /> : <div></div>}
        <div style={{float: 'right'}}>
          {this.state.message.date}
        </div>
          From: {this.state.message.senderName}
        <Divider />
          Subject: {this.state.message.subject}
        <Divider />
          {this.state.message.text}
        <Divider />
        <Button icon='reply' onClick={this.handleReply}/>
        {this.state.reply ? <Composer recipient={this.state.message.senderName}/> : <div></div>}

      </Container>
  )
}
```

Comment: I might have an idea of why it's doing that. It *sounds* like you're setting `this.state.redirect`, which is triggering the component to reload. When the component reloads, it redirects to `/messages`, but you have already fired a method that is trying to setState after the component has already been unmounted? Does that sound like what could be happening?

Comment: sort of, i deleted the componentDidMount() and it works. I need a way to redirect and prevent the component from calling componentDidMount()

edit: it's not calling componentDidMount after the redirect, but according the user above the ajax is setting state after unmounting. interesting....